# Is it possible to boot straight into a SSH terminal?

Tags: ssh, boot

I have a laptop that no longer has a HDD.  I was hoping to find a small img to flash to a flash drive and boot from that would allow me to use it as a SSH terminal.  Is there anything out there for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd imagine any reasonably new Linux image designed to run from a flash disk will suffice.  I know that PLOP will do it (but there are better solutions).  I've never bothered with them, but I'm pretty sure [Pendrive Linux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/%5C) or [Ubuntu Live](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Live_USB_creator) if you want a GUI.

Comment: Related: [Booting Linux off USB pendrives](http://superuser.com/questions/681/booting-linux-off-usb-pendrives?rq=1) and [Is it possible/practical to install and run Linux on a USB flash drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/144844/is-it-possible-practical-to-install-and-run-linux-on-a-usb-flash-drive)

Answer (score 0):

how about [xpud](http://www.xpud.org/) ? ive used it before for something similar.
its a simple light weight os that boots fast and has a web browser and ssh client

Comment: Welcome to Super User!  When answering with a recommendation for a product/software please [follow these guidelines](http://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/47225).